# Is there a way for BaseRequestHandler classes to be stateful?

Tags: python, sockets, namespaces, socketserver

**Short Question**
Using my examples below, is there a Pythonic way to share `my_object`'s actual instance with with the BaseRequestHandler class?

**Background**
By definition, the BaseRequestHandler class creates a new instance for each request.  Because of this, I am struggling to try find a solution on how to get data from the `handle()` function back to the `ProtocolInterface` instance.  Note that this might be the wrong approach if I am needing to do something in `handle()` other than print to stdout.

At this point in time, I do not believe that global variables will work because `my_object` is passed in and is expected to change often (this is why `handle()` needs to see it.  To see an example client (sending bogus data) see my [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8546870/157744).  I think the biggest issue I am facing is the the socketservers are running in a background thread.

**Example of what I would like to do**

```
class ProtocolHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while(1):
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024)
            if self.data == '':
                break
            self.request.send("Success") 
            self.my_object.success = True#  <--- How can I share my_object's instance?

class ProtocolInterface():
    def __init__(self, obj, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, single_connection=False):
        self.my_object = obj # <--- This ideally is the same instance seen in ProtocolHandler
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        # Create the socket server to process in coming traffic
        if(single_connection):
            self.server = SocketServer.TCPServer((self.host, self.port), ProtocolHandler)
        else:
            self.server = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer((self.host, self.port), ProtocolHandler)

    def start(self):
        print "Server Starting on HOST: " + self.host
        server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever)
        server_thread.daemon = True
        server_thread.start()
```

Comment: The code in your `while` loop in `handle()` seems to have incorrect indentation?

Comment: @Francis Avila. I'm guessing its the way line wrapping is set for you. Minus the self.my_object it is a working example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could pass the object through the server instance:

```
self.server = SocketServer.TCPServer((self.host, self.port), ProtocolHandler)
self.server.my_object = self.my_object
```

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#server-objects) indicates that you can have access to the server instance in `handle()` as `self.server`.

Comment: Wish I would have seen that.  Works like a champ.  Thanks!

Comment: How is this useful without thread synchronization?  Multiple threads are writing to the same variable. How is the server object supposed to use or make sense of it?

Comment: @FrancisAvila: The object you expose to the base clients would have to be thread safe / implement locking.  My example code above was admittedly poorly written just using a bool.  A threading.Event with the set/clear methods would have been a better example.